# Grails openid plugin 2.0.0 RC1: getting "No such property: User exception"

Tags: grails, plugins, openid

Installed [openid plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-openid) 2.0.0 RC1 to my grails application, but I'm getting 
No such property: User exception. Can someone suggest what should be done?

```
| Error 2013-10-28 00:11:55,169 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] /Test/login/openIdCreateAccount - parameters:
username: valid_gmail@gmail.com
password2: ***
password: ***
No such property: User for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.openid.OpenIdRegisterCommand. Stacktrace follows:
Message: No such property: User for class: grails.plugin.springsecurity.openid.OpenIdRegisterCommand
   Line | Method
->> 265 | doCall   in grails.plugin.springsecurity.openid.OpenIdRegisterCommand$__clinit__closure1_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   195 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    53 | doFilter in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    49 | doFilter in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    82 | doFilter in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   695 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Do you have [Spring Security Core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) installed in the app? If the answer is no, then [RTFM](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-openid/docs/manual/guide/introduction.html).

Comment: Hi, yes it is installed. I'm getting the exception when i'm redirected after the gmail authentication and try to register a new user for the given openid.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is not fixed in RC2, I installed it 2 days ago and ran into the same problem. Actually, there are 4 errors in OpenIdController. I'll mention the details of these errors and their solutions that user2576874 fixed in his suggested answer below:

1: line 267, the class refers to grailsApplication bean in a static closure of OpenIdRegistrationCommand. The solution given here is to replace `grailsApplication` by: `grails.util.Holders.getGrailsApplication()`

2: line 286, the regEx fail when we try to register a user after an OpenId login callback. Here's a simpler regEx condition:

```
(!password.matches('^.*[a-zA-Z].*$') ||
!password.matches('^.*[0-9].*$') ||
!password.matches('^.*[!@#$%^&].*$')))
```

3: line 183, there was a mistake with the field name: `usernamePropertyName`. The right field name is `usernamePropName` as described in line 49.

4: Running the code throws a NullPointerException because of the Role class not being defined a type. The solution was to add the class type to the variable Role same like User and UserRole definition. The following code was added right after line 255 of OpenIdConroller:

`Role = grailsApplication.getClassForName(conf.authority.className)`

Thx

Answer (score 2):

This is the version which worked for me. Could you pls release based on this a new RC3 from the plugin?

```
/* Copyright 2013 SpringSource.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package grails.plugin.springsecurity.openid

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException

/**
 * Manages associating OpenIDs with application users, both by creating a new local user
 * associated with an OpenID and also by associating a new OpenID to an existing account.
 */
@Secured('permitAll')
class OpenIdController implements InitializingBean {

    /** Dependency injection for daoAuthenticationProvider. */
    def daoAuthenticationProvider

    /** Dependency injection for the grailsApplication. */
    def grailsApplication

    /** Dependency injection for OpenIDAuthenticationFilter. */
    def openIDAuthenticationFilter

    /** Dependency injection for the requestCache. */
    def requestCache

    /** Dependency injection for the springSecurityService. */
    def springSecurityService

    private Class User
    private Class UserRole
    private Class Role
    private String usernamePropName
    private String passwordPropertyName
    private String enabledPropertyName
    private String roleNameField

    static defaultAction = 'auth'
    static scope = 'singleton'

    /**
     * Shows the login page. The user has the choice between using an OpenID and a username
     * and password for a local account. If an OpenID authentication is successful but there
     * is no corresponding local account, they'll be redirected to createAccount to create
     * a new account, or click through to linkAccount to associate the OpenID with an
     * existing local account.
     */
    def auth() {

        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

        if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
            return
        }

        [openIdPostUrl: "$request.contextPath$openIDAuthenticationFilter.filterProcessesUrl",
         daoPostUrl:    "$request.contextPath$config.apf.filterProcessesUrl",
         persistentRememberMe: config.rememberMe.persistent,
         rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter,
         openidIdentifier: config.openid.claimedIdentityFieldName]
    }

    /**
     * Initially we're redirected here after a UserNotFoundException with a valid OpenID
     * authentication. This action is specified by the openid.registration.createAccountUri
     * attribute.
     * <p/>
     * The GSP displays the OpenID that was received by the external provider and keeps it
     * in the session rather than passing it between submits so the user has no opportunity
     * to change it.
     */
    def createAccount(OpenIdRegisterCommand command) {

        String openId = session[OpenIdAuthenticationFailureHandler.LAST_OPENID_USERNAME]
        if (!openId) {
            flash.error = 'Sorry, an OpenID was not found'
            return [command: command]
        }

        if (!request.post) {
            // show the form
            command.clearErrors()
            copyFromAttributeExchange command
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        if (!createNewAccount(command.username, command.password, openId)) {
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        authenticateAndRedirect command.username
    }

    /**
     * The registration page has a link to this action so an existing user who successfully
     * authenticated with an OpenID can associate it with their account for future logins.
     */
    def linkAccount(OpenIdLinkAccountCommand command) {

        String openId = session[OpenIdAuthenticationFailureHandler.LAST_OPENID_USERNAME]
        if (!openId) {
            flash.error = 'Sorry, an OpenID was not found'
            return [command: command]
        }

        if (!request.post) {
            // show the form
            command.clearErrors()
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        if (command.hasErrors()) {
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        try {
            registerAccountOpenId command.username, command.password, openId
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            flash.error = 'Sorry, no user was found with that username and password'
            return [command: command, openId: openId]
        }

        authenticateAndRedirect command.username
    }

    /**
     * Authenticate the user for real now that the account exists/is linked and redirect
     * to the originally-requested uri if there's a SavedRequest.
     *
     * @param username the user's login name
     */
    protected void authenticateAndRedirect(String username) {
        session.removeAttribute OpenIdAuthenticationFailureHandler.LAST_OPENID_USERNAME
        session.removeAttribute OpenIdAuthenticationFailureHandler.LAST_OPENID_ATTRIBUTES

        springSecurityService.reauthenticate username

        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        def savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response)
        if (savedRequest && !config.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault) {
            redirect url: savedRequest.redirectUrl
        }
        else {
            redirect uri: config.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the user instance and grant any roles that are specified in the config
     * for new users.
     * @param username  the username
     * @param password  the password
     * @param openId  the associated OpenID
     * @return  true if successful
     */
    protected boolean createNewAccount(String username, String password, String openId) {
        boolean created = User.withTransaction { status ->
            def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig

            password = encodePassword(password)
            def user = User.newInstance((usernamePropName): username,
                                        (passwordPropertyName): password,
                                        (enabledPropertyName): true)

            user.addToOpenIds(url: openId)

            if (!user.save()) {
                return false
            }

            for (roleName in config.openid.registration.roleNames) {
                UserRole.create user, Role.findWhere((roleNameField): roleName)
            }
            return true
        }
        return created
    }

    protected String encodePassword(String password) {
        def config = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        def encode = config.openid.encodePassword
        if (!(encode instanceof Boolean)) encode = false
        if (encode) {
            password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
        }
        password
    }

    /**
     * Associates an OpenID with an existing account. Needs the user's password to ensure
     * that the user owns that account, and authenticates to verify before linking.
     * @param username  the username
     * @param password  the password
     * @param openId  the associated OpenID
     */
    protected void registerAccountOpenId(String username, String password, String openId) {
        // check that the user exists, password is valid, etc. - doesn't actually log in or log out,
        // just checks that user exists, password is valid, account not locked, etc.
        daoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)

        User.withTransaction { status ->
            def user = User.findWhere((usernamePropName): username)
            user.addToOpenIds(url: openId)
            if (!user.validate()) {
                status.setRollbackOnly()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * For the initial form display, copy any registered AX values into the command.
     * @param command  the command
     */
    protected void copyFromAttributeExchange(OpenIdRegisterCommand command) {
        List attributes = session[OpenIdAuthenticationFailureHandler.LAST_OPENID_ATTRIBUTES] ?: []
        for (attribute in attributes) {
            // TODO document
            String name = attribute.name
            if (command.hasProperty(name)) {
                command."$name" = attribute.values[0]
            }
        }
    }

    void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
        usernamePropName = conf.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
        passwordPropertyName = conf.userLookup.passwordPropertyName
        enabledPropertyName = conf.userLookup.enabledPropertyName
        roleNameField = conf.authority.nameField
        User = grailsApplication.getClassForName(conf.userLookup.userDomainClassName)
        UserRole = grailsApplication.getClassForName(conf.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName)
        Role = grailsApplication.getClassForName(conf.authority.className)
    }
}

class OpenIdRegisterCommand {

    String username = ""
    String password = ""
    String password2 = ""

    static constraints = {

        username blank: false, validator: { String username, command ->

            def User = grails.util.Holders.getGrailsApplication().getClassForName(SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName)

            User.withNewSession { session ->
                if (username) {
                    boolean exists = User.createCriteria().count {
                        eq SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName, username
                    }
                    if (exists) {
                        return 'openIdRegisterCommand.username.error.unique'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        password blank: false, minSize: 8, maxSize: 64, validator: { password, command ->
            if (command.username && command.username.equals(password)) {
                return 'openIdRegisterCommand.password.error.username'
            }

            if (password && password.length() >= 8 && password.length() <= 64 &&
                    (!password.matches('^.*[a-zA-Z].*$') ||
                    !password.matches('^.*[0-9].*$') ||
                    !password.matches('^.*[!@#$%^&].*$'))
                ) {
                return 'openIdRegisterCommand.password.error.strength'
            }

        }
        password2 validator: { password2, command ->
            if (command.password != password2) {
                return 'openIdRegisterCommand.password2.error.mismatch'
            }
        }
    }
}

class OpenIdLinkAccountCommand {

    String username = ""
    String password = ""

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false
        password blank: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, and I fixed it and released 2.0-RC2. Please update to that version and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, i updated, but i get now the same error for the grailsApplication. It looks like the OpenIdRegisterCommand does not see in the closure the grailsApplication from the parent class in this line: def User = grailsApplication.getClassForName(SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName)

Comment: Hi, could you pls release a new version, RC3, with the solution provided?